# Bash recursive function not executing properly

Tags: bash, recursion, factorial

I have a simple `factorial` recursive function defined here. it works okay until `num=5` but later on, it starts giving garbage values. I'm reading the `num` from the user and then feeding it into the recursive function.  I'm not able to figure out the issue as I'm new to the arithmetic side of bash.

```
function fact {
    if (( $1==1 ))
    then
        return 1
    else
        prev=$(( $1-1 ))
        fact $prev
        prev_fact=$?
        this_fact=$( expr $1 \* $prev_fact )
        # this_fact=$(( $1 * $prev_fact )) This also works the same way as above
        return $this_fact
    fi
}

echo -n "Enter the number: "
read num
fact $num
val=$?
echo "Factorial of "$num" is "$val""
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return codes are limited to the range 0-255. That's bad news for ol' `fact` here because anything larger than `5! = 120` will overflow.

Return codes are intended to be used to signal success and failure, not for general integer data. To "return" a value from a function you should instead echo it to stdout and use `$(...)` in the caller to capture it.

```
function fact {
    if (($1 == 1))
    then
        echo 1
    else
        prev=$(($1 - 1))
        prev_fact=$(fact "$prev")
        echo $(($1 * prev_fact))
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just use this variable $var to store/print data

```
fact(){
    (($1 > 1)) && {
         local prev=$(($1 - 1))
         fact $prev
         val=$(($1 * $val))
    } || val=1
}

read -p "Enter the number: " num
fact $num
echo "Factorial of '$num' is '$val'"
```